# Issue with SOSL search API

Tags: sosl

I am using salesforce API to do a SOSL search with the CJK charcters. But I am getting more irrelevent results. So when I search in the salesforce doc I got an information like **"In Chinese, Japanese, and Korean (CJK), words are delimited by pairs of CJK type characters."**. I want to know what are these pair of characters. I have to remove/replace those characters in my application logic.

Can any one help me on this ...???

Note: I already posted this question in salesforce discussion board but I didn't get any response. Can any one answer/solve my issue...??? Below I am giving you the link http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Java-Development/Problem-with-SOSL-search/td-p/704671

Thanx in advance for your help. Amar

Comment: Please try to find specific tags and avoid using very general tags such as 'salesforce-crm'. This helps you attract the right people to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Fiske has responded on developerforce.com:

"I think what the documentation is saying is that when presented with a string of CJK characters, such as (I'm using ASCII for clarity, just pretend these are CJK):
ABCDE

words are inferred by grabbing pairs of characters. So searching for that string would effectively be a search for
AB or BC or CD or DE

Hopefully this helps you refine your search to get better results.
"